# Grounds for having a one to one relationship between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

If I have two different types of user, Parent and Child. They have identical fields, however a Child has a one to many relationship with exams, a relationship that does not exist for Parents.

Would Parent and Child best be modelled as a single table, or combined?

What if I have two different types of user, Parent and Child. They are the same apart from a child belongs to a school (a school has many children)

again, Would Parent and Child best be modelled as a single table, or combined?

Comment: I think you should have 2 tables : one for Parents, and one for Childs, with a "one to many" integrity constraint between them. As a Parent can have one or many Childs ;)

Comment: If the data contained in the records are the same then they should be in the same table. So say you have person records containing fields "age", "height", "weight" and "type" where type differentiates "parent" or "child" (if that's even necessary) it doesn't matter whether they're in the same table or not but, you'd usually put them in the same table to make it easier to look for people in your database. If the child records need to contain foreign keys that aren't relevant to parent records then, for sure, put them in different tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They have identical fields, however a Child has a one to many relationship with exams

Even when fields are the same, different *constraints<sup>1</sup>* means you are dealing with logically separate entities. Absent other factors, separate entities should be put into separate physical tables.

There may, however, be reasons to the contrary. For example, if there is a key that needs to be unique across parents *and* children combined, or there is another table that needs to reference all of them etc...

If that's the case, then logically both "parent" and "child" are inheriting from the "person", containing the common constraints (and fields). Such "inheritance" can be represented by either storing the whole hierarchy into a single table (and setting unused "portion" to NULL), or by separating all three "classes" into their own tables, and referencing the "base class" from "inherited classes", for example<sup>2</sup>:

[image]

PERSON_ID is unique across all parents and children. In addition to that, OTHER_TABLE can reference it directly, instead of having to separately reference PARENT_ID or CHILD_ID.

---

*<sup>1</sup> A foreign key in this case.*

*<sup>2</sup> A very simplified model that just illustrates the point above and does not try to model everything you mentioned in your question*

Answer (score 3):

Parent and Child both are Persons without a doubt.  You should never put them in seperate tables.

Only time separates them : what if a Child becomes a parent?

A parent easily can have children for that you need a relationship table.
Als a relationship table is the right way to model school membership.

so tables here :

```
person
is_child_of (many to many, join table) --> relations between persons can be is_parent_of
```

plain and simple

Remember : being a child is a *relation* from person to person. 
How would you model a grandchild if needed?  Yet another table?  And a great grandchild?

And supose you are fine with that and you make a lot of tables for a lot of "kind of" relationships, an all of a sudden you want you have to add a field (day of birth) or alter a field format : you have to do it in all your different tables.

Comment: thanks, let me play devils advocate to fully understand your reasoning. What if I constrained the problem to a three year period, nullifying your argument about only time separating them?

Comment: even than. More over : constraints more often than not, change  : the infamous 2K problem is an example of that : all databases there where'nt meant to be around after 2000.  The eiffel tower was set up for only a short period too :)

Answer (score 2):

You have described three different entities in your question -- Parents, Child(ren), and Exams.  You have shows how the three differ in the their relationships to each other.

From everything in your question, I would say that you have three entities and you should set them up as such in your database.  That is, Parent and Child should have separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would break children out into a separate table for the simple reason that a parent may have many children (if not now, maybe in the future).

More than the current need, it is also important to consider what may happen in the future even if it doesn't make sense now. You may have two parent users who want to administrate one child and that child's exams.

Consider the most possible future functional requirements and program with them in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If the items are modeled differently in your system, I would say that they should be different tables.  Just because parents and children both have similar properties (names, ages, etc.), does not mean they will always have the same relationships with other entities in your database.  You could have parent and child be in same table with column relating child to parent, but this just leads to awkward self-join queries when trying to represent this relationship. This in itself can become very odd if a child has two parents.  So to me you would have a number of different tables:

```
parent
child
child_to_parent (many-to-many join table)
school
child_to_school (one school to many children)
classes
child_to_classes (many-to-many)
classes_exams (one-to-many table relating exams to classes)
child_to_classes_exams (many-to-many table relating children to exams for specific classes)
* and maybe things like the following
teacher
teacher_to_classes (many-to-many)
```

Now certainly in your class design (if you are using OOP), you could have child and parent extend from a common "person" class which would handle logic for setting common properties.

Comment: "does not mean they will always have the same relationships with other entities in your database" -> of course it doesn't.  That's why you should model those relationships in seperate tables

Comment: @Peter Absolutely they should be in separate tables IMO.

Comment: how to model a grandchild with your model?

Comment: @Peter That wasn't specified as something that is needed. No need to introduce a tree-structure here when one is not being called for.  In the context of whether a child at the school has a grandparent as a guardian, then perhaps 'parent' table might better be labelled as 'guardian' so that it is non-specific to whether someone is a biological parent or not.

Comment: to be honest : I make a living on what "wasn't specified" Things always change. Modeling is about coping with future change and not be able to answer to "whatif" questions is often a model smell.

Comment: and another thing is like  I aske  in my answwer : what *if* a child becomes a parent?  You could say that there is a time constraint too, but that wasn't stated in the question.

Comment: @Peter Perhaps if you have a school that is grades K-12 and you need to track the child of the 18 year old girl in 12th grade who had a baby at age 13 who is now in kindergarten you may have such a use case. Even then, my guess is that having that girl listed once in the parent table and once in the child table would not be that big of a problem, as both would be used in the system in different context.  Why would there be a need to absolutely have them treated as the same person?  Premature design for a use case that doesn't will not reasonably exist in the near future is often totally wasted

Comment: Doubling data?  A same person in two records?  I think you are taking this a bit too far... Premature design? Yes indeed in the parent/child model.  The person approach is not only more general, but more maintenance friendly and future proof.  It does not make queries odd, it is a general practice in design.  In each case you should NEVER  have duplicate records in master data, if that's the outcome you should know that you are on the wrong track..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42369/discussion-between-peter-and-mike-brant)